# Model constraints are not working with Faker ( Django )

Tags: django, django-models, faker, pytest-django

I am just starting to use pytest and faker for testing

while trying to **create** text for a field in testing db the constraints are being ignored and i don't know how to fix it.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Note(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=5)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

**factories.py**

```
import factory
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
from mynotes_api.models import Note


class NoteFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Note

    body = fake.text()
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from pytest_factoryboy import register
from tests.factories import NoteFactory

register(NoteFactory)

@pytest.fixture
def new_user1(db, note_factory):
    note = note_factory.create()
    return note
```

**test_ex1.py**

```
import pytest

def test_product(new_user1):
    note = new_user1
    print(note.body)
    assert True
```

**test output**
[image]

the problem as visible in output is that the length of the text generated and being stored in the testing db is more than 5.

kindly guide me in this regard.

Comment: Passing max_length to a TextField does not create a constraint, use a CharField instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#textfield

Comment: @IainShelvington do we have to write validations functions if we want to use TextField in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Iain Shelvington**'s advice to use a [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) is the main issue here. It will enforce the database constraint.

Django offers more types of validation that cannot be enforced by the database. These will not be checked on a `model.save` call:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a
> model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators
> on any fields that are included in your form.

See [How validators are run](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run).